# Nested Stack in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I recently got access to one of the Dev Account of AWS.

I was going through CloudFormation templates and did not understand the behavior of some templates.

I clicked on one of the CloudFormation stack names and inside it shows me some 5 nested stacks. When I checked the template of this stack I could not find any code which justifies that it uses nested stacks. So I could not find any keywords like below in the template:

```
    "Type": "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack

               OR

    Transform" : {
   "Name" : "AWS::Include",
```

Here I am confused if the main stack does not have any of the above functions then how does it show 5 nested stacks inside it?

Comment: Can you post the templates or give a link to them?

Comment: Firstly this is a question you should be asking your developers. We can't see these templates, we can't see "the above functions", all your question has said is "I'm confused" and you haven't really asked any question that we can answer. However a nested stack is one which is created by another stack, so if you look at the template of the stack which contains the nested stacks you should find some stack resources. That's all I can say. As to why, you need to ask whoever wrote it.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a macro adding the resources dynamically. Try looking for:

[Transform:](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html)

You can also check out the processed template from the Console. Go to the Template for the root stack and toggle the `View processed template` button in that section.